# azure data factory compression limits

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm going to prepare some export functionality from `blob storage`. For this I'd like to use azure data factory (ADF) where I will use copy activity with `target data set blob storage` using `zip compression`. I just can't find some information on how big that target zip file could be. In my case it's something between few hundreds of MB to few hundreds of GB. Is there some documentation or does someone have experiences with creating huge (>100GB) zip files with ADF?

Answer (score 0):

**Data Factory is designed to scale to handle petabytes of data.**

However, Limit for payload size doesn't relate to the amount of data you can move and process with Azure Data Factory.

To know more about Azure Data Factory limits you can refer [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits#azure-data-factory-limits)